# Visual Studio Code Startup Problems

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

So I just downloaded Visual Studio Code. I tried to run a very small but simple code right after I downloaded it. VSC told me that I didnt have a launch.json and wouldnt let me run the code to the console. I randomly clicked on the first option I thought would fix it and moved on. Now, when I try to run my code it opens a new window of VSC and I have no idea why or how to fix it and get what I want. I also couldnt find the tech support for VSC so here I am. If it helps, this is the code I was trying run:

let string = 'abC';

console.log(string.length);

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *I randomly clicked on the first option I thought would fix it and moved on.* Turns out it's helpful if you know what you're clicking.

Comment: Delete the launch json file to revert

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Visual Studio, also make sure to delete all the residual files including those in AppData folder. It could help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to tell you that you can run javascript on the command line without any executer (like nodejs). Or you can run it in any browser.

I think that when you open just a file via vscode, it also opens a window of the last directory you used on a new window